# Combobox change height vb6?

Tags: combobox, vb6

I have a combobox that's being populated from the SQL-SERVER with a list of names. What I'm trying to do is, let the user click on the drop down and show all names without scrolling down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the font of combo is the same as the forms one

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function MoveWindow Lib "user32" _
                (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
                ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal updt As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim I As Long

    Me.ScaleMode = vbPixels
    With Combo1
        MoveWindow .hWnd, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height + (Me.TextHeight("W") * 11), 0 'why 11 and not 10? i realy don't know right now
    End With

    For I = 1 To 20
        Combo1.AddItem "Item " & I
    Next I

End Sub
```